# How to make field readonly based on group with XML. Odoo 16

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-16

I added a custom field in 'purchase.order' model:

```
class PurchaseOrder(models.Model):
   _inherit = 'purchase.order'
   
   custom_field = fields.Char(string="Custom Field")
```

I want to set "readonly" = 0 only for admin group, so I added this form views

```
<record id="purchase_order_form_extend" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">purchase.order.form.extend</field>
        <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase.purchase_order_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <field name="partner_ref" position="after">
                <field name="custom_field" attrs="{'readonly': 1}"/>
            </field>
        </field>
    </record>


    <record id="view_order_form_custom_readonly" model="ir.ui.view">
    <field name="name">purchase.order.form.readonly.custom</field>
    <field name="model">purchase.order</field>
    <field name="inherit_id" ref="purchase_order_form_extend"/>
    <field name="mode">primary</field>
    <field name="groups_id" eval="[(6, 0, [ref('base.user_admin')])]"/>
    <field name="arch" type="xml">
        <field name='custom_field' position="attributes">
               <attribute name="attrs">{'readonly': 0}</attribute>
        </field>
    </field>
```

But still not woking... ,
Any idea about what's wrong please?
Thanks.

Comment: Why `<field name="mode">primary</field>`? This should lead to Odoo not loading the "admin" view. Just remove the line.

Answer (score 0):

They removed the use of `groups_id` in [inherited views](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/16.0/odoo/addons/base/models/ir_ui_view.py#L482)

> Inherited view cannot have 'Groups' define on the record. Use 'groups' attributes inside the view definition

To make the field readonly for non admin users using `groups` attribute, duplicate the field and use `!` in groups: